# Laravel can't access or load pictures from Storage/public anymore

Tags: php, laravel, image, local-storage, laravel-8

For some reason, the pictures aren't loading at all anymore on the blade view, I tried display a picture I pasted on the storage folder manually not dynamically but it didn't show either so I'm pretty sure the problem is that the server can't access the content of the storage file?

I am storing the pictures in the database using the following code:

```
    if($request->hasFile('logo')){
            $formFields['logo'] = $request->file('logo')->store('logos','public');
        }
```

then accessing it in the blade view using

```
<img
            class="w-48 mr-6 md:block"
            src="{{$album->logo? asset('storage/'.$album->logo) : asset('/images/noalbum.png')}}"
            alt=""
        />
```

I made sure the pictures are properly stored in the database and in the storage file:

[image]

I tried some solutions I found online, as running `php artisan storage:link` or manually deleting the folder then creating it again, or replacing `asset('storage/'.$album->logo)` with `Storage::url($album->logo)` but none of that seemed to work. What's weird is that this same code snippets used to work just 2-3 days ago just fine. I'm assumed it was because I'm using livewire or constantly pushing commits of this project in git, but it didn't seem to make much sense in my head.

The Github repository file if needed to access any other files:
[github link](https://github.com/thsurgeonofdeath/Quasimoto_albums_laravel)

Comment: is the image there if you hard type the path into the browser?    if you go to /public/  remove the storage symlink, then re run PHP artisan storage link.  also verify that your image is in /storage/app/public/logos/XXXXXX

Comment: I figured what was causing this and I really don't understand why it's been causing it, apparently when I renamed the project folder it stopped loading pictures? so i renamed it back to what it was originally and the pictures started loading normally again... really weird

Comment: that would be the symlink losing reference to the path

Comment: Any idea how can i rename the folder safely? without causing this issue

Comment: after you rename the folder, you need to remove the public/storage  file (symlink)  and re run the PHP artisan storage:link command that will create the smylink from storage/app/public/ to public/storage